# How to drag and retrieve data from a column in another sheet, thereby skipping a given number of rows in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column (E) containing data in sheet "insulineratio". On another new sheet I want to retrieve those data in column A from this first column "insulineratio" by dragging down. I want this retrieval to begin from cell `insulineratio!E3`, however then the retrieval must skip 3 rows and retrieve from `insulineratio!E7`, then `insulineratio!E11` and so on ...

In column B of my new sheet I want the same thing to happen, only commencing from cell `insulineratio!E4`, skip 3 rows, `insulineratio!E8` and so on.

Column C, same thing commencing from `insulineratio!E5`. Column D, same thing commencing from `insulineratio!E6` and so on.

Can anybody help me with the formula to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `INDEX()` function, and use for the row parameter `4*ROW()-1`.

This will give you in rows 1,2,3... the values from rows 3, 7, 11, ... in the other sheet.